# Tab with drop down does not maintain height on hover in modern browsers

Tags: css

This is a database driven menu that IE6 likes fine but modern browsers
not so much.

http://www.tanyadischler.com/index2.php

http://www.tanyadischler.com/menu.css

If you roll along the menu you will see in Chrome, Safari, FF, IE7 etc
that the hover on Gallery appears to have less height and to be too
wide so that it appears under News.

CSS validates:
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://www.tanyadischler.com/index2.php&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple:

```
.menu li {width: 111px;}
.menu ul ul a, .menu ul ul a:visited {padding:10px 0 10px 5px; width:128px; 
    border-width: 0px 1px 1px;}
```

Therefore the anchors will have a effective width of (128 + 5 + 1 + 1)px = 135px, and the containing list elements only 111px, therefore the anchors will overflow, because overflow is not set to hidden. Either correct the width of the list elements or of the anchors.

Comment: I get the gist of what you're saying but where did you get the 111px? That line in menu.css is .menu li {float:left; width:130px; position:relative; } And the number 111 does not appear anywhere in the file.

Comment: No, not in that file, but when you use Firebug to show the styles, then there is file stu.css that has that directive in line 8.

Comment: Argh!!!  I cloned off menu.css and was using the copy, stu.css.  And then forgot I had done that!  What a waste of time.  Thank you very much for helping me out with this.